# how to create an iMessage chatroom

Tags: objective-c, imessage

I'm looking to create a imessage chatroom and I was curious what base elements are used in this. 
I've been researching and it is beginning to look like a uiTableView is used to create the chat messenger. Any insight on where I should even start would be great,
Thanks in advance